# Fonts don't work with UTF-8

Tags: html, css, unicode, utf-8, fonts

I have some problems about fonts. If I use some Roman characters, those characters are translated in my native language and font works, but if I use my language's characters, font doesn't work.

For example: If I try "Contact" it's translated in "კონტაქტ" (my language) and font works but if I try "კონტაქტ" in HTML font doesn't care. How can I use my font to work both of them?

```
@font-face {

    font-family: 'Avaza_Mtavruli';
    src: url('../fonts/avazam-webfont.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
    src: url('../fonts/avazam-webfont.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
    url('../fonts/avazam-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('../fonts/avazam-webfont.ttf')  format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
    url('../fonts/avazam-webfont.svg') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}


selector{

    font-family:"Avaza_Mtavruli"
}
```

Right directory, no errors.

Comment: You'll have to be a bit more specific than “it doesn't work”. First of all, you have the actual Georgian characters in your HTML, right?

Comment: If I use Georgian characters in HTML nothing happen, and if i use Roman characters, they are translated in Georgian and font works

Comment: Then I guess you have a font which has those glyphs assigned to Latin code points. Such fonts cannot be used on the web according to the standards, note for instance how browsers ignore `font-family: "Symbol";` in CSS. The only solution is to find another web font which properly assigns glyphs to Georgian code points.